# How can I get rid of Safari 5's "awesome bar"? 

Tags: safari

Safari 5 came with a copycat of Firefox "awesome" bar, completing text as your type an url with history of previous title pages you've seen, and not just previous URLs.

How to get rid of this annoyance?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it and I don't know if it'll solve your problem, but Shaun Inman created a Safari extension called [SMRT](http://shauninman.com/archive/2010/08/25/smrt) that disables its auto-complete behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following :

```
default write com.apple.Safari DebugSafari4IncludeFancyURLCompletionList -bool NO
default write com.apple.Safari DebugSafari5IncludeFancyURLCompletionList -bool NO
# note the 5 instead of 4 in the second command.
```

I know the one with `4` exists, but I'm not sure for the one with `5`.

At least, you could try these commands (each one or both), they won't hurt the system.

Comment: Does this actually work for anyone on Safari 5?